# Skin pores analysis using Blob detection in OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, feature-detection

I am working on a project where I want to detect the pores in a given skin image. 
I have tried various methods(HoughCircles, BlobDetection and Contours) from OpenCv using Java, however, I am unable to proceed.

HoughCircles is showing me all false circles and same is the case with contours. 
My current code uses blob detection technique which is also not showing what is required. Sample code is written below:

```
public void detectBlob() {

    Mat orig = Highgui.imread("skin_pore.jpg",Highgui.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    Mat MatOut= new Mat();

    FeatureDetector blobDetector;

    blobDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SIFT);

    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

    blobDetector.detect(orig,keypoints1); 

    org.opencv.core.Scalar cores = new org.opencv.core.Scalar(0,0,255);

    org.opencv.features2d.Features2d.drawKeypoints(orig,keypoints1,MatOut,cores,2);

    Highgui.imwrite("PhotoOut.jpg", MatOut);
}
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BlobDetection bd = new BlobDetection();
        bd.detectBlob();
    }
```

When I tried the same code using FeatureDetector.SIMPLEBLOB instead of FeatureDetector.SIFT it shows almost 0 blobs.

The output and source images are attached for the above code. Source Image
[image]

Output Image using SIFT
[image]

Is there any other algorithm which can help in achieving the result or what can be the appropriate approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did not ask anything in your question I won't give you an answer. More some general advice.

That you tried to solve that problem using the named algorithms clearly shows that you have absolutely no clue what you are doing. You lack the very basics of image processing. 
It's like trying to win vs decent chess player if you don't even know how the figures can move.

I highly recommend that you get yourself a beginners book, read it and make sure you understand its contents. Then do some more research on the algorithms you want to use, befor you use them.
You cannot take some arbitrary image, feed it into some random feature detection algorithm you find on the internet and expect to succeed.

Hough transform for cirles for example is good for finding circle shaped contours of a roughly known radius. If you know how it works internally you will know why it is not a good idea to use it on your image.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Hough_Transform

Blobdetection and contour based algorithms might work, but only after a lot of pre-processing. Your image is not very "segmentation-friendly"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_detection

A SIFT detector usually has to be taught using reference images and reference keypoints. I don't see this either in your code.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform

Please note that reading those wikipedia articles will only give you a first idea of what's going on. You have to read a lot more.

Always start at the beginning of your processing chain. Can you get better images? (Better means more suitable for what you want to detect). This is like 10% camera and 90% illumination. I don't think detecting skin pores is a classical task for shitty cellphone pictures so why not put a bit effort into your imaging setup?

First rule of image processing: crap in = crap out. You should at least change the angle of illumination or even better approach like shape from shading.

An image optimized for the detection you have to do is cruicial. It will make image processing so much easier.

Then pre-processing: How can you transform the image you have into something you can easily extract features from?

And so on...

Comment: I know some basics of image processing after doing some research. However, yes I am new to this and also I have to show the basic working functionality (just to detect at least the skin pores) by the end of this week. So due to this I want some help through this channel.

I have to use a cellphone camera to get the image and process it. This image was just used for testing purpose.

Comment: whoever demands that you detect skin pores from a cellphone image has no idea what he's doing or talking about and is of very doubtful character. I think the proper term is a**hole. Most cellphone cameras if not all cannot even resolve skin pores properly... But if you have to use a cellphone your first mistake is not using a cellphone image. Try to make a usable picture with your phone as a first step!

Comment: I have argued upon the same and now it is decided that we should take images from a proper device which was being used earlier in the lab. 
Now my question is , when I have a proper image I still do not have a proper solution to detect pores . The above algorithm as said fails to do so and I have very less time to do research. If you can help me finding the logic would be a great help.

Comment: provide an image of that proper device then. use some sort of darkfield illumination if possible to get a good contrast. try to illuminate as evenly as possible to ease further image processing.